# Gnuplot: plot only final dataset

Tags: dataset, gnuplot

I would like a way to plot only the last (final) dataset in a file that contains multiple datasets. Can anyone suggest a way of doing that? e.g. if I know there are exactly 10 datasets in the file then:

```
plot 'myfile.txt' index 9
```

would plot the final one. I don't know in advance how many datasets there will be though. On the off-chance that it might work, I tried

```
plot 'myfile.txt' index -1
```

but no joy. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have gnuplot 4.6.0+, you can use the `stats` command to get that information:

```
stats 'foo.dat' name 'foo'
stats 'bar.dat' name 'bar'

plot 'foo.dat' index (foo_blocks-1) title 'bar', \
     'bar.dat' index (bar_blocks-1) title 'foo'
```

The `name 'prefix'` key-value pair makes gnuplot save its statistical results in variables with the prefix `prefix` instead of `STATS`.

For details type `? stats` at the gnuplot command line.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice tip - I didn't know about that utility. Sadly though I presume there is no way of making that work if I want to plot two separate files on the same graph in that way?